# a question about null space

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

This is the example from Friedberg's Linear Algebra book. It is giving an example about Null space (denoted by $N(T)$), and range, denoted by $R(T)$. I don't understand is why is $N(T_{0})$=V not $0$. I thought since $N(T)$={$x \in V: T(x)=0$}, it should always be $0$, why not?

Comment: As you have mentioned, the Nullspace (or kernel) of a linear transformation is defined as the elements in the domain which get mapped to zero. This is not always just $\{ 0\}$ (otherwise this would be a concept with very limited use, no?). $T_0$ is defined as sending everything to 0, so we have $N(T_0) = V.$

Comment: By definition, $N(T_0)=\{x\in V: T_0(x)=0\}$. It says that $T_0$ is the zero transformation, which just means that $T_0(x)=0$ for all $x\in V$. The null space is **definitely** not always just zero. I think you need to read your book more carefully since concepts like null space, eigenvalues, eigenvectors are at the core of all of mathematical theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null space of a map is the stuff in the **domain** that *gets mapped to zero*, not the value $0$ that results from the map.

Since $T_0$ maps *everything* to zero, then everything is in the null space of $T_0$.

Remember, the null space is a subspace of the domain.

Of course, $0$ (in the domain) is in the null space, but so is everything else in the case of $T_0$.

Answer (score 1):

By the null space, we mean to collect all those elements of the domain, which are mapped to zero in the codomain.

You are provided with $T_0 : V \rightarrow W$, which is defined as $T_0 \left( x \right) = 0$, $\forall x \in V$. Therefore, every element gets mapped to the zero element of the codomain and hence each element is in the null space. That is same as saying $V \subseteq N \left( T_0 \right)$. However, to construct the null space, we are collecting elements from $V$, so that the inclusion $N \left( T_0 \right) \subseteq V$ trivially holds. Therefore, the null space of $T_0$ is whole of $V$.

Answer (score 1):

The zero transformation is defined by the fact that $T(v)=0$ for all $v \in V$. So the nullspace of the zero transformation must be the entire domain space, in this case $V$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\textsf{N}(\textsf{T}_0)$ is the set of all vectors $v$ in $\textsf V$ so that $\textsf{T}_0(v) = \textit0$, but, actually, **every** vector in $\textsf{V}$ satisfies this. Hence $\textsf{N}(\textsf{T}_0) = \textsf V.
$

Answer (score 1):

$N(T_0)=V$ because he said that $T_0$ is the **zero transformation** (for any $v\in V, T_0(v)= 0_w$)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are right. But perhaps an example will make things more clear. Consider the linear map $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$
T(x_1, x_2) = (x_1, 0)
$$
Then $(0,1)$ is not the zero vector, and yet
$$
T(0,1) = (0, 0)
$$
In fact, $N(T) = \{0\} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $T_0$ is a zero transformation so,  $T_0(v)=0$ for all vectors in $V$.so $N(T_0)=V$.